# solr syntax for date range query

Tags: solr

I wonder what is the correct syntax for solr date range query... I think I got it right but it does not work and an error is thrown:

Query is `date_day_tdt:[2015-09-01T00:00:00Z TO 2015-09-01T23:59:59Z]`

And the query url after escaping chars is:

```
q=date_day_tdt%3A%5C%5B2015%5C-09%5C-01T00%5C%3A00%5C%3A00Z%5C+TO%5C+2015%5C-09%5C-01T23%5C%3A59%5C%3A59Z%5C%5D&start=0
```

The error is: Invalid Date in Date Math String:
`[2015-09-01T00:00:00Z TO 2015-09-01T23:59:59Z]`'

When I query individually `date_day_tdt:2015-09-01T00:00:00Z or date_day_tdt:2015-09-01T23:59:59Z` both worked

Comment: Just one more optimization hint, you need not to mention time,
you can just add dates without time 
[2015-09-01T00:00:00Z TO 2015-09-01T23:59:59Z]
is equivalent to 
[2015-09-01 TO 2015-09-01]

Comment: ^ note on "don't need time" - that's only if the implementation/server running SOLR isn't using strict validation on dates with any non-registered formats failing

Comment: ^ note (2) on "don't need time" - Solr has multiple types of date fields - dates, date ranges and the rather restrictive TrieDateField that uses a subset of the ISO-8601 standard https://solr.apache.org/docs/6_2_0/solr-core/org/apache/solr/schema/TrieDateField.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not escape the brackets and other special character with \

Your actual search string is:

```
date_day_tdt:\[2015\-09\-01T00\:00\:00Z\ TO\ 2015\-09\-01T23\:59\:59Z\]
```

**Hint1:**
Use your query directly. The browser or solr client api will escape the characters correctly:

```
date_day_tdt:[2015-09-01T00:00:00Z TO 2015-09-01T23:59:59Z]
```

**Hint 2:**
Append echoParams=all to the query. Then the parsed params are printed in the solr result.